# AsyncTask in Multiple Tabs with different content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have an app that has 10 tabs (categorys) Each tab requires a different set of data to be called from a PHP/MySQL WebService on a remote server.

i'm passing category id (catid) to doinBackground function in parameter then i retrive the json and build the Array iList:

```
@Override
protected List doInBackground(String... params) {

     int catid = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

    ProductApi  prd = new ProductApi();

    try {

        List<ProductDetails> arrayproduct = prd.ProductApi(catid);

        ArrayList<Data> al = new ArrayList<Data>();

        for (ProductDetails prditem : arrayproduct) {

            al.add(new Data(new String[] { 
                    "Product", 
                    prditem.getProductName(),
                    prditem.getProductPrice()},
                    new int[] { R.drawable.popularity_img5 }));
            }

        iList.addAll(al);   

    return arrayproduct;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

the problem i'm facing
is that i have the same product list in all tabs , because i don't know where i have to execute my AsyncTask on every horizontal Scroll , retrieve the current CatId (Category Id) and load new data on the current tab the user is viewing .
do i have to create many adapter as categories tabs i have ?

i Can get the CatId ( Category Id ) on instantiateItem but it don't let me execute the loaddata method   getItemCount() in this case return Array List 0

```
@Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int pos) {


            int CatId = tinydb.getInt("CategoryId"+pos);

            Log.w("PageAdapter", "-------------------------------------instantiateItem pos:"+pos+" CatId: "+CatId);


            final View v = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.pager_card_view, null);

            RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
            // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
            // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
            recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
             //LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager llm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            llm.setOrientation(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
             // use a linear layout manager
            recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

            // create an Object for Adapter
            CardAdapter ca = new CardAdapter();
            // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
            recList.setAdapter(ca);



            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).enableActionBarAutoHide(recList);

            container.addView(v,
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);




            return v;
        }
```

Comment: Where starting `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: i start  here :   private void setupView(View v) {
  
  String[] catid = {"21"};  
  loadData(catid);
  
  initPager(v);
 }

Comment: @Mourad - Always edit and update the question with your code and leave a comment that you have done it :)

Comment: ok sorry i'm new to this forum any help ?

Comment: How about running the task in the activity, and the fragments can call methods on the activity to get the data?

Comment: this solution don't work